# How do I create makefile for in windows with cygwin in C++?

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I am just trying to make my first simple makefile for the ***.cpp*** file. The .cpp file, main.cpp, is simple as it is a simple hello world program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I tried creating a makefile in CodeBlocks by going File > New > Empty File and naming it 'makefile' in the same directory as main.cpp. In my 'makefile', I wrote it as:

```
output: main.o
    g++ main.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

using tabs. However, when I'm in the directory with Cygwin, I type 'make' and it says

> "*** missing separator. Stop".

I'm not sure if the tabs were recognized even though I typed it in there. Is there a specific process in windows when I create my own makefile?

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't have tabs, did you double check that? Check it with a different editor in case code-blocks emulates tabs.

Comment: Yes, I put cat -e -t -v  makefile, and it doesn't show '^I', which represents tab. The thing is, I'm under the impression a makefile does not have an extension. I tried using notepad, but it creates a .txt file. Unless anyone has suggestion, I'll try looking for a different editor.

Comment: `Cygwin` probably comes with `nano` or `vim`

Comment: Okay, installing nano seems to do the trick. I can replace the spaces (which code blocks put there) with tab.

Comment: There must be a setting in codeblocks to stop it from replacing the tabs with spaces.

Comment: There are lots of programmer's editors out there and most have a mode for makefiles.  However, if you prefer and you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make (3.82 or above) you can set the `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable in make to any character you'd like to use as a recipe prefix instead of TAB.